# Is there a way to create pull request templates for specific branches - not just main? GITHUB

Tags: github, pull-request

so i've read these docs

https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository

and they outline out to create a PR template for pull requests to main.

this is almost exactly what I need, except i would like this pr template to appear for all PR requestings to a QA branch, which would not be the default branch. main would remain the default branch.

is this possible? can't seem to find anything online supporting this

in summary i need the PR template to be triggered when creating a PR to a specific branch, not just main (in this case the branch would be called QA)

i've tried things like

.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/qa.md but that doesnt work :/

Comment: Did you try with `.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE_QA.md` ?